# Rewrite rule with nginx replace get variable with slach

Tags: nginx

I've been reading everything i could find for two days now but nothing seems to work

I have an url like this

http://www.mysite.com/auction.php?category=23140

and want make a rewrite rule so it will appears like that

http://www.mysite.com/auction/category/23140.php

I do that only in order to build seo friendly url but so far nothing have worked.

rewrite ^/auction.php?category=(.*)$ /auction/category/$1 last;

It look so simple i realy don't know why it doesn't work.

Should i put this line in the server block or the location block ? Is the regex wrong ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

At first, pls remember **rewrite** in nginx **does not match query string, only uri**.

For example, in this url: "**/auction.php?category=23140**", uri is **/auction.php** and query string is **category=23140**

So in your case, the correct rule should be:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ "^/auction\.php\?category=[0-9]+(.*)?$" ) {
    rewrite "^.*$" /auction/category/$arg_category break; 
}
```

Above is just a example, you can change it according to your case. And also you can find the usage of [$request_uri](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_uri) and [$arg_PARAMETER](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24arg_PARAMETER) from the nginx manual.

Comment: I made the following rule but now the file is not found , that's the first time i use url rewriting so things are not clear at all for me

Comment: if ( $request_uri ~ "^/auction-japan\.php\?category=(.*)$" ) {     rewrite "^.*$" /auction-japan/category/$1.php break;  }

Comment: Pay attention to the $1, you didn't match it in the rewrite directive. Using $args_PARAMETER to reference the args you want in query string. Pls read carefully the example I wrote above, especially $args_PARAMETER.

Comment: You are using "^.*$" in rewrite and this regex do not pick up any thing. So $1 in rewrite is empty, here should use $arg_category instead. pls refer the manual, it's not a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it backwards, try this.

```
rewrite ^/auction/([^/]*)/([0-9]*) /auction.php?$1=$2
```

piece of advice, if this is a custom application you're writing without a framework, you could find a routing module that you could use and it would help you do every thing easily.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the answer but unfortunatly it's still doesn't work. Don't understand why.

Comment: Try that as well but doesn't work. This is driving me crazy. location / { rewrite /auction-japan.php?category=(\d+)$ /auction-japan/category/$1.php last; }