# nginx rewrite does not forward $arg_page to upstream

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have

```
rewrite (?i)^/museums/Andorra /search-results?country=ad&page=$arg_page break;
// 246 more similar rewrites for other country codes.
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7001;
```

and yet, when I go to `/museums/Andorra&page=1` in the browser, the `REQUEST_URI` in the proxied app is set to `/search-results?country=ad&page=`

nginx is a bit old: 1.14.2 if that matters. This answer from 2013 however https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739990/308851 seems to suggests an `$arg` variable in the replacement part of rewrite should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `rewrite` can use `$arg_` parameters in the rewritten URI, although you do not necessarily need to.

There are two problems:

You do not need to add `&page=$arg_page` to the end of the rewritten URI, as `rewrite` will automatically append the original query string unless the rewritten URI ends with a `?`. So your existing `rewrite` statement will generate `/search-results?country=ad&page=1&page=1` (assuming that the `$arg_page` variable is set).

Use either:

```
rewrite (?i)^/museums/Andorra /search-results?country=ad break;
```

Or:

```
rewrite (?i)^/museums/Andorra /search-results?country=ad&page=$arg_page? break;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

---

Your test URL does not contain a query string.

Use:

```
/museums/Andorra?page=1
```

Comment: "Your test URL does not contain a query string." <= Oh my, it's the _outgoing_ URL rewrite JavaScript which is not even in this question, I am blind, it keeps a '&' when it should change it to a '?'.